# TypeScript fails running playground examples

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm trying to get basic functionality of JQuery and SignalR to work with TypeScript in Vs2012, its been a long hasle to get where Iam. Using the latest JQuery and SignalR from DefinitelyTyped @ GitHub, I can't even get it to compile let alone get my code to compile without JQuery begins to spas out and report 300 errors atleast, first because of keys that had to extend from numbers and then because of generics that apparently seems unsupported.

Information:

- I'm using the latest (0.9.0.1) TypeScript
- I'm using the latest DefinitelyTyped JQuery library (tested without other code, same result)
- I've tried setting the build options for TypeScript to ES5 and ES3
- I've tried using other versions of JQuery with no better results.
- Everything works with basic javascript no problem.
- TypeScript can compile and therefore generate basic typescript code.
- TypeScript CANNOT compile the PlayGround example with generics, but CAN compile the classes example WITHOUT generics.
- Errors at bottom - Couldn't post ss so added as code.

-----------Greeter Generics Class- Playground example------------------------

```
class Greeter<T> {
    greeting: T;
    constructor(message: T) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return this.greeting;
    }
}

var greeter = new Greeter<string>("Hello, world");

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function () {
    alert(greeter.greet());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

-----------Greeter Class - Playground example------------------------

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

var greeter = new Greeter("world");

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerText = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(greeter.greet());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

-----------My Code - not that it should matter much------------------------

```
interface sandboxCommunication extends HubConnection {
    addNewMessageToPage: Function;
    newContosoChatMessage: Function;
}

interface SignalR {
    chat: HubConnection;
    sbconnection: sandboxCommunication;
}

class SandBox {

    // Constructor
    constructor() { 
            var sbconnection = $.connection.sbconnection;
            // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
            sbconnection.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                $('#messages').append('<li><strong>' + name
            + '</strong>: ' + message + '</li>');
            };


            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#broadcast").click(function () {
                    // Call the chat method on the server
                    sbconnection.newContosoChatMessage($('#msg').val());
                });
            });

            function connectionReady() {
                $('#messages').append('<li><strong>' + "Server: "
            + '</strong>: ' + "Connected" + '</li>');
            };

            $.connection.hub.error(function () {
                alert("An error occured");
            });
            $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#broadcast").click(function () {
                    // Call the chat method on the server
                    sbconnection.newContosoChatMessage($('#msg').val());
                });
                        }).done(connectionReady);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert("Could not Connect!");
                });

            $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:56808/SBCHub'
            $.connection.hub.start();
    }
}
```

--------------------Errors------------------------------

```
Error   1   Expected '{'    D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  1   14  SandBox.ts
Error   2   The name 'T' does not exist in the current scope    D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  3   26  SandBox.ts
Error   3   The name 'T' does not exist in the current scope    D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  3   26  SandBox.ts
Error   4   The name 'T' does not exist in the current scope    D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  3   26  SandBox.ts
Error   5   The name 'T' does not exist in the current scope    D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  3   26  SandBox.ts
Error   6   The name 'T' does not exist in the current scope    D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  3   26  SandBox.ts
Error   7   The property 'greeting' does not exist on value of type 'Greeter'   D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  4   14  SandBox.ts
Error   8   The property 'greeting' does not exist on value of type 'Greeter'   D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  7   21  SandBox.ts
Error   9   Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'bool' and 'string' D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  11  15  SandBox.ts
Error   10  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target   D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  11  19  SandBox.ts
Error   11  The name 'string' does not exist in the current scope   D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  11  27  SandBox.ts
Error   12  The property 'greet' does not exist on value of type 'bool' D:\\.Sandbox\TypeScript\SandBox.ts  16  19  SandBox.ts
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not running TS 0.9.x (despite what you said). I suggest you uninstall your current version, and  then, download + install the version from here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) At first I was like, no way. But investigating further than doing a tsc -version check I found that Visual Studio had an old installation lying around that the installer did not uninstall or overwrite, because it was downloaded and installed through the add in manager. As soon as I uninstalled it through the add-in manager it had automatically registered the new one without needing to even reinstall it.